# Non constant meromorphic section

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology

Let X be a compact Riemann Surface and E be a holomorphic vector bundle.

> Does there always exist a non constant meromorphic section?

I know that for $E=O_X$ the result is true(i.e there exist non constant meromorphic functions) by using finite dimensionality of the sheaf cohomologies. Since E also has finite dimension cohomology can I generalise this?

Comment: Remind me how the proof goes for $E = \mathcal O_X$ using cohomology?

Comment: Fix point p. Use U=disc around p and V=X-p as open cover and consider 1st Cech cohomology. Cech cohomology is finite dimensional (as sheaf cohomology is). Hence around p, $1/z,1/z^2...$ cannot all be linearly independent. Thus you get a relation which is exactly a meromorphic function with a potential pole at p

Comment: Tensor with a line bundle $L^*$ with $\deg(L)\ll 0$ so $\deg(L^*\otimes E)\gg 0$, hence nontrivial global section exists, and so you have $L\to E$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? I think you're using Riemann Roch to conclude that L*tensorE has non trivial section. Can you explain the last line and how it implies a meromorphic section of E?

Comment: From the case $E=O_X$ you also get all other holomorphic line bundles $L$.  Then you find some $L$ such that $h^0(L^*\otimes E)>0$ (Riemann-Roch tells you this is possible for $L^*$ of high enough degree).  Now an element $s\in H^0(X;L^*\otimes E)$ is precisely giving a map $L\xrightarrow{s} E$ of vector bundles and we already know we can find a lot of nonconstant meromorphic sections of $L$.  So we just need $s$ not the zero map, whose existence is what $h^0(L^*\otimes E)>0$ guarantees.

Comment: Thanks! I believe you are identifying Hom(L,E) with L* tensor E.